# Register bundle KnpSnappyBundle on a Symfony3 project without Composer

Tags: symfony

In symfony 2 I managed to do it, but now in symfony 3 it is giving me problems, I do not want to use composer, some can tell me step by step that I have to configure to work in symfony 3

Comment: «I do not want to use composer» I fear you are in deep trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolvi en symfony 3 tenemos que agregar en los ficheros app.php y app_dev-php

$loader = require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Knp', **DIR**.'/../vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle');